# Console output using rpy2 does not work in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

Using Jupyter Notebook, when I execute a function from an R package (in my case Climatol) from a notebook that uses the R kernel, messages are displayed as output that report the procedures that are being done. Nothing new.

[image]

The code block used is this:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(climatol)

# Apply function (from R kernel)
homogen('Vel',2011,2012,tinc='6 hour',expl=TRUE)
```

Now, using the Python kernel from another notebook, when I call the same function through `rpy2` applying the same parameters, I don't get the same messages that appear in the previous image. Instead I get this:
[image]

This time, the code block used is this:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

importr('maps')
importr('mapdata')
importr('climatol')

# Apply function ( from Python kernel)
r["homogen"]("Vel",2011,2012,tinc="6 hour",expl=r['as.logical']("T"))
```

I ran the mentioned Python code from Sublime Text and in this case the messages are displayed:
[image]

The messages are also displayed when running the code from the Windows console, which leads me to think that the downside is Jupyter. That being said, how can I get those messages using Jupyter?

I'm using Python 3.7 and the version of rpy2 is 2.9.4

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the full code block of your rpy2 (enough lines for a [MCVE]) and not [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Are you running in a Python 2 or Python 3 kernel? What happens if your run `.py` script at command line outside of any IDE? What if you wrap the call in `print(...)`.

Comment: Hello @Parfait. I have edited the question according to your recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/climatol/versions/3.1.2/topics/homogen) indicates: *This function does not return any value, its results being saved to files with the same base name as the input files, and extensions*.  So even if no output renders on screen in Jupyter, is results saved to an external file?

Comment: Hello. Yes, the output are saved to an external file, but I need them to appear in the console because I need to generate a report of procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rpy2 it not fully supported on Windows. Callbacks used to set how R output is handled are likely not working, which results in the issue you are observing.

**If** this improves in will be in more recent rpy2 versions. The latest rpy2 release is 3.3.6 for example.

Otherwise, for better compatibility on Windows consider running rpy2/jupyter in Docker, or if it works in a WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).